# Query Mongo collection for all documents with empty array nested in an array

Tags: mongodb-query

I have documents that look like this in a collection called movies:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51c272623021490007000001"),
  "movies": [
    {
      "name": "Booty Call"
      "play_times": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Bulletproof"
      "play_times": [{...},{...}]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to query for documents where "play_times" is not empty or null.  Basically I only care about movies with play times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query for separate array elements within documents, that is not possible AFAIK. If you want to get documents which have non-empty `play_times`, then use [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/) operator:

```
movies.play_times : { $size : { $gt : 0} }
```

To check if field exists, there is an [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) operator.

Comment: Will this return documents who have one or more non-empty ```play_times``` or documents whose movies ALL have non-empty ```play_times```?

Comment: Try it and find yourself :) AFAIK, it will return those which have at least one non-empty movie. MongoDB is not very good at querying of nested arrays unfortunately... You may want to redesign your database to flatten it out (MongoDB is good at flat redundant records which don't need joins, because they already look like joined tables - try it).

Comment: It didn't work so I was wondering what you expected.  Of course I'm going to try it myself